# Fetching problem with Macports

Tags: macports

I'm running macports on a late 2013 MBP. I'm having problems with macport being unable to download the package files. I tried installing 'git +svn' and not only did the entire dependency resolution take a bit more than one hour, once it got done and moved into the fetching phase it couldn't find any files to download.
I checked in safari and the files are there sure enough but the port installer can't seem to find them.
I've tried at home as well and my mac mini there has no problems finding the packages and installing them but the MBP can't. And the mac mini is much much faster at dependency resolution as well.

I've googled around without really finding anything so I'm at wits end here.
There must be something strange with my installation but I can't figure out what.

The log:

```
info:fetch --->  expat-2.1.0.tar.gz doesn't seem to exist in /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/expat
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://osl.no.distfiles.macports.org/expat
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30003 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://skylink.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30002 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://lil.fr.distfiles.macports.org/expat
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30004 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://mse.uk.distfiles.macports.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/expat
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30003 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://nue.de.distfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/expat
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30004 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://fco.it.distfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports-distfiles/expat
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30005 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30003 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30005 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30003 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://netassist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30004 milliseconds
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch expat-2.1.0.tar.gz from http://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.1.0
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Connection timed out after 30003 milliseconds
```

EDIT:
It seems like there is a problem with curl:
The following doesn't work:

> curl http://nue.de.distfiles.macports.org
>   it just times out.

Comment: What does the log show?

Comment: Just a thought: have you checked your DNS settings?

Comment: DNS works perfectly for everything else. I can, as I said, access the files with safari without a problem.

Comment: Can you access some of the files in Terminal via curl?

Comment: @patrix I tried with one that I could access through the browser but it didn't work with curl. That is strange.

Comment: Can you add the curl part (and the error you've got) to the question?

Comment: @patrix I tried with this: curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall and that works! is there something with the hosts?

Comment: @patrix 'curl http://nue.de.distfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz' and I just get a timeout (the http part is there, it just isn't shown

Comment: With DNS, or with redirection (that's what the `L` option takes care of)

Comment: Curling expat.tar.gz works for me, so DNS is a prime suspect :-) Do you have LittleSnitch or similar installed?

Comment: @patrix if we assume that safaris uses the same dns as curl and safari works then this should indicate that the problem isn't in dns unless you mean redirect or something similar. Yes, I have little snitch installed.

Comment: Any LittleSnitch rules which might impact network access from Terminal? Or just turn it off completely for a few minutes and try without

Comment: I've tried removing all terminal rules and this works for ssh (i.e. when i try to ssh somewhere I get the normal dialog box) but when I try curl nothing happens. It's like it doesn't even try to connect to the network

Comment: And so I found it. Comparing the output from -v on 2 machines showed that the problematic one tried to access an ip not on the lan. Further study found an env var, http_proxy, was set on the problem machine. Removing it solved the problem. Question is, why did it suddenly start causing problems since macport worked 2 weeks ago.

Comment: When was the env variable set - possibly limn the last 2 weeks?

Comment: @Mark unless it was set automatically, no. Far earlier than that. It might be some network changes done behind the curtains where there once was a http proxy, deprecated and now finally removed.

Answer (score 1):

And the problem was the env var, http_proxy. Somehow it suddenly started to make a difference. 
Shout-out to @patrix for the help!